# Always have to clear VAR to log in to Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I moved my site from a different domain. I can only log in if I do the following:

Change my password in PHPmyAdmin.
Delete VAR/CACHE.
Login using a cleared cache/incognito browser.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to delete your cookies and cache in the browser you're using or use another browser?

Comment: Did you change your URL settings in `core_config_data`?

Comment: Hi. Done both. I tend to have to log in FTP, delete VAR/CACHE and then log in using Incognito browser.